# Trying to get the colour of the cursor

Tags: colors, cursor, autohotkey

I was wondering if anyone can help me.
 I would like to get colour of the pixel of my cursor (if the cursor is at position x1,y1 I want to look at x1+5,y1+5 which I know the value of the colour. 
BUT it gives me the values beneath the cursor. Is there a way to pixelsearch the cursor?

*The reason I want to do this is detect when the cursor has changed into another cursor image.*

Thank you.

```
h::
loop
{
sleep 50
MouseGetPos, MouseX, MouseY
X1:=MouseX+5
Y1:=MouseY+5

PixelGetColor, color1, %X1%, %Y1%

Tooltip, PixelColour: %color1%



 If(%color1% == 0XF0FDFF)
 MsgBox cursor has changed
}


 esc::exitapp
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer can be found within this screen capture script: https://github.com/cswoyer/AutoHotkey/blob/master/ScreenCapture.ahk It has an option for capturing the cursor in the screen shot. Looks like there's some DLL tomfoolery involved.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the cursor colour specifically is impossible as far as I know. It will usually take on the text content's colour which should be fine in most cases.

Comment: I dont want to change the cursor color I just want to get its value.
at x+5, y+5 if x,y are the mouses cordinates

Answer (score 0):

do you have your issue already resolved? Do you need to check if not image, but state of your cursor has changed?
If yes, then please have a look at variable `A_Cursor` that represents the current state of your cursor.

Check it out with simple:

```
Sleep, 10
MsgBox %A_Cursor%
```

You can check easily if your cursor is an arrow or maybe waiting for something, etc... Hopefully someone will find that useful.
Best regards!